# How to find and Validate an elements "Title" with selenium webdriver Firefox

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-firefoxdriver

```
<div class="t">
<h4 class="u-mb5">Web Architect</h4>
<h5 class="u-mb5">
<span>TSR Consulting Services, Inc.</span>
<span class="u-pl10">NY, New York, United States</span>
</h5>....
```

I want to check the title of a Search result. Title = "Web Architect"
I can locate the element via Xpath , but I want to locate and take that TEXT from `<h4...</h4>` so that I can make a check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

Locate the `WebElement` first and then use `getText()` method to get the text as follows:

```
    WebElement my_element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("your_xpath"));
    String my_text = my_element.getText();
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question

Comment: easier than I expected , somehow  I was not able to get the text by getText() ,  now it is all cool.

Comment: @HellYeah2511 Glad to be able to help you. Thanks